# Formally, what is the meaning of sigma notation with two variables in the subscript and one variable in the superscipt?

Tags: summation, notation

For example, what would $\displaystyle \sum _{i,j=1} ^n a_i a_j$ mean?

Comment: It means that you sum over every combination of $i,j$ subject to the given bounds.  Thus $\sum_{i,j=1}^2 a_ia_j=a_1a_1+a_1a_2+a_2a_1+a_2a_2$.

Comment: Its a bit messy of a notation, but I would expect that they mean by that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(a_ia_j)$.  As you nest more and more summations together, the space required by writing each of the summation symbols can grow to be too much, prompting people to take shortcuts by combining them.

Comment: @JMoravitz. Thank you very much. It was very confusing, but you made my day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j
$$
that is both indices range from $1$ to $n$.

*In this particular case*, you can even simplify it further as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j = \sum_{i=1}^na_i\sum_{j=1}^n a_j = \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_i\right)^2
$$
since the term $a_ia_j$ can be decoupled between $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Even if $a$ is not the same, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i h_j$?

Comment: @Avra Yes, that would be the case there too.